# $.post() jquery method timesout what are some reasons it does

Tags: jquery, timeout, .post

What are some reasons it could timeout, just can't figure it out?

Comment: Check if the request is coming to the server side and see how server is responding.

Answer (score 2):

$.post() itself doesn't timeout, what [times out is the web server](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#timeout) or the server side script handling the request.

Answer (score 0):

As babiker said, post doesnt time out, the request itself does.  Try manually accesing the ajax URL thru the address bar.  You wont be able to pass POST parameters this way, but hopefully you can still learn something from it or add get parameters if they do something.

Is the file at the ajax url yours?  If so try putting a simple text out in the beginning of the page (you dont mention the server-side language, but for example in php a good choice would be `die("page opened");`).  If that text displays when you manually open the page, then the timeout has to do with whats happening later in the server-side code.